# aurelia if.bind how to do?

Tags: aurelia

I have a spinner , this spinner should just be showing if the user click in the `<a>` button element, right now the spinner is showing  all the time, can someone help me on this? thank you.

```
<a class="btn btn-action" href="#/user" bs-tooltip="title.bind: 'user'">
    <i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <loading-feedback
          is-loading.bind="true"
          message.bind="Loading.."></loading-feedback>
</a>
```

Comment: You have `is-loading.bind="true"` and there is no where you are setting it to false. Why would you expect any different behavior than what you are describing? Are you trying to set it to false in the view model? If so, please include that code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
<a class="btn btn-action" href="#/user" bs-tooltip="title.bind: 'user'" click.delegate="handleClick()">
    <i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <loading-feedback is-loading.bind="loading" message.bind="Loading.."></loading-feedback>
</a>
```

In the view-model you can do following -

```
let loading = false;
handleClick() {
    this.loading = true;
}
```

click.delegate can be used to call some method. And attribute.bind can be used to bind a variable to the attribute. This way you can bind the value of *loading* to *is-loading* attribute and call *handleClick()* to change that value when the anchor is clicked. There seem to be other issues with you code though, if you are binding something to an attribute it has to be a variable not a literal.